# How should I register my Sonata application's new admin class?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am using the Sonata admin bundle to build a backend for a blog. I have created a new Post entity and used `sonata:admin:generate` to generate an admin class called PostAdmin. This admin class extends AbstractAdmin. So far so good.

In accordance with https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html, I add the following code to my class:

```
public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
{

    die('At least the validate() method is being called.'); 

    $errorElement
        ->with('author')
        ->assertNotBlank()
        ->assertNotNull()
        ->end();

    parent::validate($errorElement, $object); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

... but my die() statement does not appear to get called. (Also, when I remove the die() call, the assertions appear to get ignored, as I can leave my "author" field blank and still save a record.)

====

UPDATE #1: Per https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/conditional_validation.html, I tried throwing an exception instead of dying. Even with this better debugging technique, it appears that the method is not getting called.

UPDATE #2: It looks like none of the methods in my PostAdmin class are being called at all. **Is there a place I need to register that PostAdmin class in order for its methods to be called?**

Comment: apparently, the `validate()` method is not called.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like none of the methods in my PostAdmin class are getting called at all. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. It's embarrassing.

There was an old file called PostAdminOld.php that contained a duplicate of my PostAdmin class. Running `make install` on my project in a fit of desperation, I saw the following message that helped me pin down the problem:

```
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "AppBundle\Admin\PostAdmin" was found in both "/usr/src/app/src/AppBundle/Admin/PostAdminOld.php" and "/usr/src/app/src/AppBundle/Admin/PostAdmin.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "AppBundle\Controller\PostAdminController" was found in both "/usr/src/app/src/AppBundle/Controller/PostAdminControllerOld.php" and "/usr/src/app/src/AppBundle/Controller/PostAdminController.php", the first will be used.
```

... and that was that. Removing the old admin class definition allowed me to see my more recent changes.